# How can I upload files into shared b2drop.eudat(owncloud) repository using curl?

Tags: curl, console, wget, owncloud

Following link: https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7 holds the files and folders (publicly accessible). Please not that no user name and password is required.

I can download the zip file via:

```
wget https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7/download
```

This will generate a download file. I can unzip it via: `unzip download`

On the website's GUI, when I click plus sign and than `upload` sign it opens a section where I can select which files I want to download. I would like to do all this operations via console.

[image]
[image]

[Q] From its GUI I could also upload files. Is it possible to upload files using console using `curl` or `wget`?

Following command did not help.

```
curl --upload-file run.sh https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7/
```

I have also tried from following link: https://github.com/owncloud/pyocclient but it did not helped.

```
oc = owncloud.Client('https://b2drop.eudat.eu/')
oc.login('username@domain.edu', password )
oc.put_file("https:/b2drop.eudat.eu/s/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7", "path/to/upload/run.sh")
oc.put_file("/s/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7", "path/to/upload/run.sh")
oc.put_file("/DfQlm5J42nEGnH7", "path/to/upload/run.sh")
```

Thank you for your valuable time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the analysis of network log, this is a `PUT` request to `https://b2drop.eudat.eu/public.php/webdav/<filename>` with `text/plain` content-type with a basic authentication with no password and username `DfQlm5J42nEGnH7`.

The following will upload the local file `run.sh` :

```
curl -X PUT -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
     -H 'Authorization: Basic RGZRbG01SjQybkVHbkg3Og==' \
     --data-binary '@run.sh' \
     https://b2drop.eudat.eu/public.php/webdav/run.sh
```

Note that basic authentication base64 encoded string gives `DfQlm5J42nEGnH7:` decoded (username:password)

Original network log :

[image]

Comment: Thank you. It worked! If I have a folder to upload (which may contain some sub-folders) instead of only `run.sh` or `.tar` file. Is there any easy way to upload them also? @Bertrand Martel

Comment: How did you find `RGZRbG01SjQybkVHbkg3Og==` ? For example for this new link: `https://b2drop.eudat.eu/s/30lETRKHDL8Lpr0` ? I try to encode `DfQlm5J42nEGnH7` on this site (http://www.utilities-online.info/base64/) but it gives different output which is `RGZRbG01SjQybkVHbkg3`. I guess we have to put `Og==` end of each encoded string.

Comment: Basic authentication in this case use `username:password` scheme. In your case `301ETRKHDL8Lpr0` is the username, so encode `301ETRKHDL8Lpr0:` in base64 (mind the `:`), password is blank